# C# Events compiling

Tags: c#, events, compilation

Let's say I got a Method like this:

```
private void Example(string message)
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
}
```

this will create a new Method `Timer_Elapsed`:

```
 private void T_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
     //What ever...
 }
```

as I cannot pass my message from above I use this code:

```
private void Example(string message)
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Elapsed += (s,o) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    };
}
```

Here I can use the `message` ?

I am curious how the complier is getting the value here ?

Comment: The words to google for are "c# closures". First result: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx

Comment: never heard of that before. I'll have a look thx !

Comment: You might also try looking at variable scoping.